# Calling user variable inside another variable / SQL execute task / script task

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, ssrs-2008

I want to have the following user variables:

a) DB Connection
Type: String
Scope: package

b) Business Process - Finance or sales
Type: String
Scope: package

c) Stored Procedure - If @Business Process = 'Finance' then EXEC USP_Name1 else EXEC USP_Name2
Type: String
Scope: package

d) Destination - If @Business Process = 'Finance' then Location1 else Location2
Type: String
Scope: package

My questions are as follows:

1. Is it possible to call one user variable inside the other? If yes, can someone please explain me the code as to how to do it?
2. If not, then, can this be done in a script task and / or SQL Execute task?  If yes, can someone please explain me the code as to how to do it?

Comment: Yes, this is possible. You can fill a variable with an expression, this expression can contain references to other variables.

Answer (score 1):

You can set a variable based on another variable using expressions. The expression to determine the stored procedure would look something like:

```
(@[User::BusinessProcess] == "Finance") ? "USP_Name1" : "USP_Name2"
```

You can then set `SQLStatementSource` of an `SQL Execute Task` to the variable that contains the above expression.

The same applies to destination. You can set the destination using an expression on your connection.

Answer (score 0):

An easier option is to use if statements in your query. You can do this in the dataset query in SSRS or in a stored procedure that you pass the parameters to.

```
--select databse
if @DBConnection = 'Finance'
    use Location1 
else 
    use Location2

--run stored procedure
if @BusinessProcess = 'Finance'
    EXEC USP_Name1
else
    EXEC USP_Name2
```